# I have 5 columns in Datagrid .Among that 2 columns value should get from String on run time

Tags: c#, asp.net

Greetings to all

Actually i'm developing a web application Which will generate DataGrid,Button and a Label at run time depends upon the value return from database.
Eg:
if return value is 2 then the 3 controls(datagrid,button and label) will generate twice.like shown below

[image]

Application working Procedure is.On click on search button the above 3 controls are generated and bind the datagrid.I have achieved this using repeater.
Now what i need is....inside that datagrid i have a button called refresh.When the Refresh button is clicked the gross weight and volume in the datagrid should display the string value,remaining columns should not get change.

Here is my aspx code:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeaterSearchResult_ItemDataBound" ID="repeaterSearchResult">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="textBoxSearch"  ForeColor="White" width="25%" runat="server" 
              Text="<%#Container.DataItem%>"></asp:Label>
         <asp:Button ID="BTNAdd" runat="server" Text="Add"  OnClick="button_click"/>
         <br />
         <asp:DataGrid ID="dgLCL" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              ShowFooter="FALSE" CellPadding="3" OnItemCommand="dgLCL_Select" 
              OnDeleteCommand="dgLCL_Delete">
              <asp:BoundColumn DataField="GrossUOMType" HeaderText="Type">
              </asp:BoundColumn>
              <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Volume" HeaderText="Volume">
              </asp:BoundColumn>
              <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="DELETE">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="IMGBTNDelete" 
                        ImageUrl="~/AppImages/grid-icon-delete.jpg"
                        ToolTip="Delete"  CommandName="DeleteItem" 
                        OnClientClick="javascript:return confirmDelete();"
                        AlternateText="Delete" />
                 </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateColumn>
              <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Add">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="IMGBTNAdd" 
                           ImageUrl="~/AppImages/grid-icon-add.jpg"
                           ToolTip="Insert"  CommandName="InsertItem" 
                           AlternateText="Insert" />
                   </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateColumn>
          </Columns>
        <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" ForeColor="#000066" BackColor="White" 
                    Mode="NumericPages">
        </PagerStyle>
                                                </asp:DataGrid><br />
```

and my code behind is:

```
protected void repeaterSearchResult_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            string Flag = Session["Flag"].ToString();
            if (Flag=="B") 
            {
                e.Item.FindControl("textBoxSearch").Visible = false;
                e.Item.FindControl("BTNAdd").Visible = false;
            }
            DataGrid gv = e.Item.FindControl("dgLCL") as DataGrid;
            //
            Label label = e.Item.FindControl("textBoxSearch") as Label;
            Session["Label"] = label.Text;
            Session["FlagB"] = Flag;
            Session["GV"] = gv;
            gridbind(label.Text, Flag, gv);
        }


        void gridbind(string label,string Flag,DataGrid gv)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Session["Loading"] != null)
                {
                    PortLName.Text = Session["Loading"].ToString();
                }
                if (Session["Destination"] != null)
                {
                    PortDName.Text = Session["Destination"].ToString();
                }
                string SFRID = label;
                if (Flag == "L")
                {
                    sql = "Select MasterNo , MasterDate,GrossWt,GrossUOMType,Volume,tBLg_NUPKId from VW_TransLCLMaster  where tBLG_mDOC_NUPKID ='107' and tBLG_NUIsActive=1 and PortOfDischargeName='" + SFRID + "'";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    if (gv != null)
                    {
                        gv.DataSource = ds;
                        gv.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
```

as shown in above image **i need the string values should assign to grosswt and volume on refresh button click**.

Please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your datagrid columns add another column

```
       <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Refresh">
          <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="IMGBTNRefresh" 
                   ImageUrl="~/AppImages/grid-icon-refresh.jpg"
                   ToolTip="Insert"  CommandName="Refresh" 
                   AlternateText="Refresh" />
           </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

In your DagaGrid's OnItemCommand event, set the text for both the cells as below

```
protected void dgLCL_Select(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Refresh")
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                //Change the indexes to correct column index
                e.Item.Cells[3].Text = "your dynamic gross weight text";
                e.Item.Cells[5].Text = "your dynamic volumne text";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hedge Thanks for your quick replay !!!!Let me try your solution and let you know.

Comment: Hedge can u please help me to solve my new issue asked in following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405694/how-to-use-if-condition-inside-linq  I wolud be very thankfull if i get your precious time for a moment

Comment: @Hedge Can you please help me to solve my issues which facing now which is mentioned in the following linkhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750671/how-to-select-unselect-all-child-check-box-based-on-the-header-checkbox-of-paren