# How to use if condition inside Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datagridview

I'm Developing an application which is used for Search and Bind the DataGrid. 
What the user will do is enter the part of the text and hit search button means it should Fetch the data from DB which have like textbox value and bind to datagrid.

**But my requirement is**:- In my table i have 3 fields namely ID,ChargeName and IorE.and in my datagrid i have columns like id ,Income and Expences.  What i need is **for eg:**
if i enter the charge name in textbox like "Service" and hit search means if it should search for the name in the **chargeName field** once it found if should check in **IorE field** if value is **"I"** then the ChargeName  should bind to **Income Column** in Datagrid  and if it is **"E"** then ChargeName should bind to **Expence Column** in Datagrid. I'm Using LinQ and i dont know how to use such condition in LINQ

Here is my code goes.

```
using (LQMasterChargeDataContext DB = new LQMasterChargeDataContext())
{
    var Result = from C in DB.TB_MasterCharges
                 where C.mCHR_NUIsActive == 1 && SqlMethods.Like( C.mCHR_VCName,TxtChargeName.Text.Trim())
                 select new { C.mCHR_NUPKId,
                              Income = C.mCHR_VCName
                            };

    dgSailing.DataSource = Result;
    dgSailing.DataBind();
    int Count = Result.Count();
    if (Count == 0)
    {
        LBLEXcepceValue.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
        LBLEXcepceValue.Font.Bold = true;
        LBLEXcepceValue.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
        LBLEXcepceValue.Font.Size = 10;
        LBLEXcepceValue.Text = "NO VESSEL FOUND ! ! !";
        //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ALERT", "alert('No Vessel found');", true);
    }
```

and my aspx page is like:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPChargesGrid" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DataGrid ID="dgDestination" runat="server" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#FE9B00"
                          BorderStyle="Solid" BackColor="White" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="XX-Small"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="FALSE" CellPadding="3" align="center"
                           Width="700px" OnItemCommand="dgDestination_Select">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ID" HeaderText="mFDD_mFRD_NUPKId" Visible="False">
                </asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Income" HeaderText="Income"></asp:BoundColumn>
                    <TemplateColumn>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="LBLEXcepceValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Expence").ToString().Substring(0,5) %>' ></asp:Label>
                         </ItemTemplate>
                     </TemplateColumn>
                     <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="SAVE">
                         <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="IMGBTNSave" ImageUrl="~/AppImages/Save.gif" ToolTip="Save"  CommandName="Save" 
                                   AlternateText="Save" />
                         </ItemTemplate>
                     </asp:TemplateColumn>
                </Columns>
        <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" ForeColor="#000066" BackColor="White" Mode="NumericPages"></PagerStyle>
      </asp:DataGrid>
    </contenttemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Can any on help me to solve this issue.Thanks in advance.

I bounded the DataGrid now what i want is if the value is null then one user control should display and save button(in datagrid) should be Enable.Please Help me to do that.Here is my need represent via image
[image]

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the query like this

```
var Result = from C in DB.TB_MasterCharges
                 where C.mCHR_NUIsActive == 1 && SqlMethods.Like( C.mCHR_VCName,TxtChargeName.Text.Trim())
                 select new { C.mCHR_NUPKId,
                              Income = C.IorE == "I" ? C.mCHR_VCName : string.Empty,
                              Expense = C.IorE == "E" ? C.mCHR_VCName : string.Empty
                            };
```

Then you can use a bound column for expense like below

```
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="Expense" HeaderText="Expense"></asp:BoundColumn>
```

**UPDATE**
I hope I understood your problem correctly. You can toggle the visibility of controls using the code like below

```
<TemplateColumn>
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="LBLEXcepceValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Expence") %>' 
       Visible='<%# Eval("Expence") != null && Eval("Expence") != string.Empty %>' 
       ></asp:Label>
       <asp:TextBox ID="textBoxExpenses" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("Expence") == null || Eval("Expence") == string.Empty %>'></asp:TextBox>
   </ItemTemplate>
</TemplateColumn>
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="SAVE">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="IMGBTNSave" ImageUrl="~/AppImages/Save.gif" ToolTip="Save"  CommandName="Save" 
      Visible='<%# Eval("Expence") == null || Eval("Expence") == string.Empty %>
      AlternateText="Save" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Hi Hedge !!!1ok thanks alot for your attantion for my question.Let me give a try your suggestion and let you know.

Comment: I have updated the answers.Sorry I did not understand " if both Expence and income are same it should display in same row not in separate row as shown above"

Comment: Sorry the above mentioned comment "if both Expence and income are same it should display in same row not in separate row as shown above"" was solved. and Heart full of thanks for your patient by listening my question and guiding me in a right way.i will work on your solution and if i have problem i'l come back to you...once again heart full of thanks

Comment: Hi Hedge !!!sorry for troubling you...I made changes as u mentioned but in my result nothing happens only the save button get disabled for all rows.

Comment: Hi hedge can u please help me to my anothe issue.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445020/how-to-get-the-user-control-value-which-is-nested-inside-the-datagrid-to-string