# how to get the User control Value which is nested inside the datagrid to String

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, datagrid, user-controls

I need to access the Value of User control which is present inside the data Grid.as shown below
[image]

Actually what i want is once the data is bind to the grid it will check whether there is a value in the Expence column of the Datagrid if the value is null then the user control will be visible where user can select the value and will click save. 
my aspx code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPChargesGrid" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DataGrid ID="dgDestination" runat="server" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#FE9B00"
        BorderStyle="Solid" BackColor="White" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="XX-Small AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="FALSE" CellPadding="3"       align="center" Width="700px" OnItemCommand="dgDestination_Select"
                     <Columns>
                         <asp:BoundColumn DataField="mCHR_NUPKId" HeaderText="mFDD_mFRD_NUPKId" Visible="False"></asp:BoundColumn>
                         <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Income" HeaderText="Income"></asp:BoundColumn>
                         <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Expence">
                              <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:Label ID="LBLEXcepceValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Expence") %>' > </asp:Label>
                                    <CC5:Charge ID="ChargeExpence" runat="server" />         
                              </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateColumn>
                        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="SAVE">
                             ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="IMGBTNSave" ImageUrl="~/AppImages/save.png"  CommandName="Save" />
                              </ItemTemplate>
                       </asp:TemplateColumn>
                    </Columns>
                    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" ForeColor="#000066" BackColor="White" Mode="NumericPages"> </PagerStyle>
                 </asp:DataGrid>
         </contenttemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

my CS code:

```
  protected void dgDestination_Select(Object sender, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string expence = "";
    UPGridControls.Update();
    if (e.CommandName == "Save")
        {
           string FRDID = e.Item.Cells[0].Text;
           string income =  e.Item.Cells[1].Text;   
            if (FRDID != "")
             {
        Label LBLEXcepceValue = (Label)dgDestination.Items[vLoop].FindControl("LBLEXcepceValue");

                  if (LBLEXcepceValue.Text != income)
                    expence = (dgDestination.FindControl("ChargeExpence") as UserControl).ToString();
         using (LQMasterChargesMappingDataContext DB = new LQMasterChargesMappingDataContext())
                 {
                    var newFRD = new TB_MasterChargesMapping
                    {
                         mCHM_mCHR_NUPKId_Income =mobjGenlib.ConvertLong( GetChargeID(e.Item.Cells[1].Text.ToString())),
                         mCHM_mCHR_NUPKId_Expences = mobjGenlib.ConvertLong(GetChargeID(expence)),
                         mCHM_mCMP_NUUniqueId = mobjGenlib.ConvertLong(TXTCompanyID.Text),
                         mCHM_NUIsActive = 1
                    };
                    DB.TB_MasterChargesMappings.InsertOnSubmit(newFRD);
                    DB.SubmitChanges();

                    B_MasterChargesMapping MASLEVPREMAP = DB.TB_MasterChargesMappings.OrderByDescending(C => C.mCHM_NUPKId).Where(A => A.mCHM_NUIsActive == 1 && A.mCHM_mCMP_NUUniqueId == mobjGenlib.ConvertLong(TXTCompanyID.Text)).FirstOrDefault();
                  //Insert In UserLog Report
                     mobjGenlib.InsertUserlog("mCHM", mobjGenlib.ConvertString(MASLEVPREMAP.mCHM_NUPKId), "I");
                    TB_MasterChargesMapping NewFRD = (from P in DB.TB_MasterChargesMappings where P.mCHM_mCHR_NUPKId_Income == mobjGenlib.ConvertLong(GetChargeID(e.Item.Cells[1].Text.ToString())) && P.mCHM_NUIsActive == 1 select P).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (NewFRD != null)
                    {
                      Session["ODDID"] = mobjGenlib.ConvertString(NewFRD.mCHM_NUPKId);
                }
                 }
             }
       }
}
```

please help me to et the value from user control to String.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can access your expense control like this

```
var expense= e.Item.FindControl("ChargeExpence") as yourUserControl;
```

You can define a public property in your user control, which actually gives you the value.
You can then access this property using expense object retrieved above.

Comment: thanks for your Replay Hedge!!!!!Will try out your suggestion and get back to you

Comment: Hedge hi!!!!Can you please help me to solve my issue which is mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750671/how-to-select-unselect-all-child-check-boxchild-grid-based-on-the-header-check

Answer (score 0):

You can access the control id which you want to access inside a user control. 
Try this.

```
 if (expence != null){
      //access controls here that are within yout usercontrol for example
      TextBox tb = (TextBox)expence.FinControl("YourTextBoxID");
string requiredValue = tb.Text;

    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks For your quick response....Actually i cant do as u suggest because in  expence = (dgDestination.FindControl("ChargeExpence") as UserControl).ToString(); i'm getting error...i need to know how to ge that selected rows usercontrol value to expence

Comment: You cannot get the control instance in a string object. try the below code.
var expense= e.Item.FindControl("ChargeExpence") as yourUserControl;
if (expence != null){
      //access controls here that are within yout usercontrol for example
      TextBox tb = (TextBox)expence.FinControl("YourTextBoxID");
string requiredValue = tb.Text;

    }