# How to select/unselect all child check box based on the header checkbox of parent grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox, datagridview

I am Developing a web application which consists of Datagrid nested with another datagrid.
In Parent Grid i have a Check box in the header template and in the child grid have another check box in the item template.

Functionality is:
    1.If i click on the parent check box all items in the child grid should be get checked and vice versa.
    2. I have amount column in the child grid , i need the sum of checked row's amount to be displayed in the textbox.

For EG:
    in my child grid i have 3 column with the amount field value as 100,200,300.
    If i click on Chkheader( parent grid header) then all child grid should get selected and in the textbox box it should display as (100+200+300)600.
    If i manuly uncheck the last row in the child grid then in text box it should dispaly as (100+200)300.

here is my code:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgcostOrigin" runat="server" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#FE9B00">
 <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateColumn>
        <HeaderTemplate>                                                                        
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHeader" runat="server" />
        </HeaderTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="VoucherDetailsChargeId" runat="server" Visible="False">
            <asp:DataGrid ID="dg_VoucherChargeDetails" runat="server" DataSource='<%#GetCFSDetailsO( (String) DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,           "Name") ) %>'>
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ID" HeaderText="mFRL_NUPKId" Visible="False"></asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:TemplateColumn>
                    <HeaderStyle Width="5%"></HeaderStyle>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CHKJobsOrigin" runat="server" >
                    </asp:CheckBox> 
                    </ItemTemplate>   
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
            </asp:DataGrid> 
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateColumn>
  </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

here is my Javascript for calculate total()

```
function CalculateTotalOriginCost(mcheckbox2) {
          var txtAmtOrg = mcheckbox2.id.replace("CHKJobsOrigin", "TXTCostOriginAmount");

            var AmountO = +(document.getElementById(txtAmtOrg).value + 0);

            var TotalAmountO = +(document.getElementById("TxtOriginCost").value + 0);

            if (mcheckbox2.checked == true) {
                TotalAmountO = TotalAmountO + AmountO;
            }
            else {
                TotalAmountO = TotalAmountO - AmountO;
            }
            document.getElementById("TxtOriginCost").value = TotalAmountO.toFixed(3);
            CalcYield();

         }
```

and here is for select and unselect

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[id*=chkHeader]").live("click", function () {
        var chkHeader = $(this);
        var grid = $(this).closest("table");
        $("input[type=checkbox]", grid).each(function () {
            if (chkHeader.is(":checked")) {
                $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
                $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).addClass("selected");
            } else {
                $(this).removeAttr("checked");
                $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).removeClass("selected");
            }
        });
    });
    $("[id*=CHKJobsOrigin]").live("click", function () {
        var grid = $(this).closest("table");
        var chkHeader = $("[id*=chkHeader]", grid);
        if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).removeClass("selected");
            chkHeader.removeAttr("checked");
        } else {
            $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).addClass("selected");
            if ($("[id*=CHKJobsOrigin]", grid).length == $("[id*=CHKJobsOrigin]:checked", grid).length) {
                chkHeader.attr("checked", "checked");
           var chkChild = $("[id*=CHKJobsOrigin]", grid);     
                 CalculateTotalOriginCost(chkChild); 
            }
        }

    });
</script>
```

select all and un select all is working fine,but i'm unable to display the total in the textbox.
without the select all function if i use get total it was working.
How to combine both the function.
can any one help me to solve this issue.
I need javascript function

Comment: Is this solved? I think the problem is in your javascript code where you call CalculateTotalOriginCost(chkChild), chkChild is not the single checkbox, but an array of controls. Did you debug the JavaScript code and find out what is it passing?

Comment: Ya it is resolved thanks hedge

Comment: @Hedge Hi sorry to trouble you lot i really need your help to solve my issi\ue which is mention in the follwing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884067/how-to-check-the-checkbox-partially-when-any-one-of-the-check-under-it-is-checke?noredirect=1#comment42323430_26884067       Its urgent please help me..