# how to check the checkbox partially when any one of the check under it is checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, datagridview

I am developing an application which consists of datagrid nested with another dataGrid.and the Child grid have multiple columns with checkbox in each row as  template column and in parent datagrid there will be an check box in each row.

**My Requirement:**
if the 1st row **check box in the parent grid is checked** in parent grid then in its **respected** child grid all check box should get **selected** and if **uncheck** the Parent checkbox  then its child should get **unselect** .Incase in the child grid insted of selecting all records if any **one or more** is checked then the parent grid checkbox should **Partially checked**.

Here is my aspx code:

```
 <asp:DataGrid ID="DG" runat="server" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#FE9B00"
    BorderStyle="Solid" BackColor="White" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="XX-Small"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="FALSE" CellPadding="3" align="center"
    Width="700px" OnItemDataBound="DG_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="dgRecovery_ItemCommand">

    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="chkHeader" runat="server" CommandName="SelectAll" Text="selectAll" ForeColor="Blue" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgPlusMinusSign1" runat="server" Width="15px" Height="15px" Visible="false"
                    CommandName="CmdQuoteChargeDetails" ImageUrl="~/AppImages/Plus.gif"></asp:ImageButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="CFS Name" SortExpression="Name"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Amount in Base">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ReadOnly="true" BorderStyle="None" Width="100px" Font-Size="10px" ID="TXTLinerAmountMain"
                    Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Amount") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="VoucherDetailsChargeId" runat="server" Visible="False"></td> </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="9">&nbsp;
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="11">
                            <asp:DataGrid ID="dg_VCD" runat="server" DataSource='<%#GetCFSDetailsO( (String) DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") ) %>'
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow"
                                Width="100%" CellPadding="0" GridLines="Both" ForeColor="Black"
                                OnItemDataBound="dg_VCDO_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="dg_VCDItemCommand">
                                <FooterStyle ForeColor="#000066" Height="20px" BackColor="White"></FooterStyle>
                                <SelectedItemStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" BackColor="Snow"></SelectedItemStyle>
                                <EditItemStyle BackColor="AntiqueWhite"></EditItemStyle>
                                <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="Snow"></AlternatingItemStyle>
                                <ItemStyle Height="20px" ForeColor="#000066" BackColor="Snow"></ItemStyle>
                                <HeaderStyle Font-Size="XX-Small" Font-Bold="True" Height="20px" ForeColor="white" BackColor="orange"></HeaderStyle>
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="mODC_NUPKId" HeaderText="mFRL_NUPKId" Visible="False"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                    <asp:TemplateColumn>
                                        <HeaderStyle Width="5%"></HeaderStyle>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CHKJobsOR" onclick="javascript:CalculateTotalORCost(this);" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:CheckBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CostSheetNo" HeaderText="CostSheetNo" SortExpression="CostSheetNo"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:DataGrid>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <td height="25"></td>
                </asp:PlaceHolder>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Width="0px" />
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" ForeColor="#000066" BackColor="White" Mode="NumericPages"></PagerStyle>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

here is my need visual:
[image]
can any one please help to replace the Link button with checkbox in the header and make it partially check  (parent checkbox) -  any one of the check is checked(child checkbox)
check (Parent)-  all record is checked (child grid)
Uncheck (Parent) -none of the record is selected  .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: to check and uncheck i have did with Linkbutton(using e.commandName ="") i get the selected row but i dont have an idea about how to use check box as a header in the Parent and to satisfy my need..